# Retrain Tensorflow Object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have read tutorials on how to train a new class using TensorFlow Object Detection API. But what I want to do is to add a new class to the already trained classes of a pre-trained model.

For example : MS-COCO pre-trained model has 90 classes. I want to add one more class and detect objects for 91 classes.

Answer (score 7):

Tensorflow object detection API supports starting from a pre-trained MS COCO checkpoint. Just set

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/usr/home/username/tmp/model.ckpt-#####"
from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

In your detection pipeline. (Official reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md)

You should add the images with your extra class to the coco dataset and finetune for all 91 classes, or your network might forget what it learned previously and only detect the new object.

Comment: The MS COCO checkpoint already predicts 90 classes. I have data for the new class. Now should I combine the new class's data along with MS COCO data set, create TFRecords for all 91 classes and train from the network checkpoint?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the net will probably forget about COCO. Alternatively, you can try to implement the contents of the "Learning without forgetting" paper, that shows how to use only the new data to learn without forgetting the previous task. Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.09282

Comment: @AndreaPisoni Do you know which files I need to copy when moving from a computer to another to retrain model? As you said, we need file mode.ckpt-#####. So I copy 3 file `model.ckpt-#####. data-00000-of-00001`, `model.ckpt-#####.index` and `model.ckpt-#####.meta` to the new directory. Then, I point the `fine_tune_checkpoint` to my new check point. But It found error that It cannot find my new checkpoint. After that, I copy file `checkpoint` in the old folder to new, but another error found: `Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor`. Am I missing something?