# Transfer Learning with Tensorflow's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the Object Detection API and already have a trained model for my specific object classes.

With my task, there will be more and more object classes over time. Since retraining on the combined data sets takes very long, I am interested in a way to only train the pre-trained net on the new data.

I have found this: 
[Retrain Tensorflow Object detection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591750/retrain-tensorflow-object-detection-api) but since I would need to load the checkpoint on the already trained data and train it again on a combined dataset, which contains the old data, wouldn't that lead to severe over fitting on the old data?

Answer (score 0):

No actually, we usually call this trick as fine-tune. The new training dataset containing both old classes and new classes enables CNN to learn a more general representation for all those classes.