# Custom Object detection using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have trained the object detection API using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` model to detect a custom object. But after training, the API only detects the custom object and not the objects for which the API is already trained. `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` model detect 90 objects.

Is there any way to add more classes to an existing model so that it can detect new objects along with the one it has been trained for?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572573/how-to-get-existing-model-to-recognize-additional-classes) and some answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247567/5330223).

The very last layer of the networks is softmax layer. when the network is trained, the weights of the network is optimized for the exact number of classes on the training set. So, if you need to add a new class and also the classes it was trained, the easiest way is to get the original dataset it was trained on along with your new class images. Then start the training from the pre-trained model weights. The training should converge faster as it has to do relatively little adjustments.